# Cordova build is not working in windows for android platform

Tags: cordova, android-build

I am preparing my machine to build an existing ionic1 app for android platform.

I installed `cordova@6.0.0` which is required for my project and ionic platform. Also set JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_HOME, and apache-ant in my environment variable.

When I build this app with `cordova`, I got this error.

[image]

As you can see, error is throwing from `aapt.exe` which comes from android build-tool version 27.0.3.

After googled several hours, I understood that project structure of android, generated by `cordova platform add android` command, is not valid for the current version of Android.

This is android project structure.

[image]

Since my `cordova` is pretty old (`cordova` version 6.0.0) which uses `android@5.1.1`, I tried to build with every Android build tool one by one but no luck, same error.

[image: build tool version]

So I am unable to build android app with cordova@6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I also have a quite old cordova project (because it needs to ne used with devices runing android 4.1).

I use Cordova version 7.0.1 + version 6.2.3 of the cordova android platform and it works well with android studio 3.

It's not clear if you talk about cordova itself or the version of the cordova android platform when you talk about cordova 6.0.0, but maybe you can try to upgrade both to use the same as I do and see if you see any improvements.